# Make sure jQuery delegate handler is only attached once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that attaches a jQuery delegate handler onto the click event of an element:

```
function foo() {
      $(document).delegate("#fooElement", "click, function(event) {

      });
}
```

The foo function could get called multiple times throughout the life of the page and the handler could at times be removed.  What is the best way to ensure that at most only once instance of this handler is attached at a time?  Should I do something like this to remove the handler then re-attach it:

```
function foo() {
      $(document).undelegate().delegate("#fooElement", "click, function(event) {

      });
}
```

Or do I need to keep track of a boolean `isHandlerAttached`.  Ideally, there would be an even cleaner way to do this, but I haven't found any in the jQuery documentation.

Comment: `delegate` is deprecated, You should just use `on` & `off`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `delegate` has been deprecated in favor of `on` for quite a long time. On SO, asking the "best" way, with no qualifiers, is a recipe for getting your question closed, since it depends on opinions. The code you have works on sufficiently old versions of jQuery (although you have an unterminated string), so you need to be more specific on what you're looking for.

Comment: So has `undelegate()` been deprecated http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/#entry-longdesc

Comment: Instead of repeatedly delegating and undelegating, I suggest you use a global variable that controls whether the function should do anything. Then you can just set and clear the variable.

Comment: Why using a delegate if there is a single element?

Comment: @plalx good question, maybe cuz fooElement gets inserted dynamically? ie not by the owner but a plugin...

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure that global state is a good way of implementing idempotency. I'd prefer a self-encapsulated solution like adding/removing a **specific** handler.

Comment: @Endless It may, but that plugin would be awful because it means it's initialization would have to be asynchronous and that it doesn't provide any callback mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

document is quite a generic element everyone is adding events to so i would suggest name spacing the event name. Also delegate & undelegate is deprecated and you should use on/off instead

```
$(document).off('click.foo', '#fooElement').on('click.foo', '#fooElement', function(e) {
    // put your logic in here
})
```

Comment: It would be better to remove a specific handler function. What if there are other `click.foo` handlers out there? The namespace does reduce that risk, it's still possible.